# About update product stock status function in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, stock

The deal is, I have to fix an error in a custom WooCommerce import plugin, which appeared after updating WC from 2.6 to 3.4.

It uses the 'wc_update_product_stock_status' function, and used to pass post (product) id and it's stock status as it is represented in DB ('instock' and 'outofstock', as a string). But nowadays, as I can see in the WooCommerce docs (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_update_product_stock_status.html) it accepts integer instead of string.

So, the question is - what are those integers for in/out of stock values (1/0 did not fit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look to the source code in [`wc_update_product_stock_status()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#943-956) function:

```
/**
 * Update a product's stock status.
 *
 * @param  int $product_id
 * @param  int $status
 */
function wc_update_product_stock_status( $product_id, $status ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    if ( $product ) {
        $product->set_stock_status( $status );
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

It uses the [`WC_Product` `set_stock_status()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#943-956) [**Woocommerce 3 CRUD method**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) **which uses strings** But **not integers** values:

```
/**
 * Set stock status.
 *
 * @param string $status New status.
 */
public function set_stock_status( $status = 'instock' ) {
    $valid_statuses = wc_get_product_stock_status_options();

    if ( isset( $valid_statuses[ $status ] ) ) {
        $this->set_prop( 'stock_status', $status );
    } else {
        $this->set_prop( 'stock_status', 'instock' );
    }
}
```

> So it's an error in the comment usage in [`wc_update_product_stock_status()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#943-956) function.

It still uses: `'instock'` and `'outofstock'` status strings. the default value is `'instock'`…

> The main difference is also that **stock status** is now handled as `outofstock` term for the custom taxonomy `product_visibility`

Before Woocommerce 3, **stock status** was handled as product meta data.