# Woocommerce 3.4.4 - Product Out Of Stock, error while changing product stock status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress 4.9.8 with WooCommerce 3.4.4 and PHP 5.6.37… I am not able to change the state of the stock of the product.

I've searched in Documentation of Woocommerce for `WC_Product` [`set_stock_status()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#943-956) method.

I tried: [About update product stock status function in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881095/about-update-product-stock-status-function-in-woocommerce-3/51881425#51881425)
without success.

I have decided to print the product to see if any errors have occurred in the product parameters:

- Print Product - https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10z5.png;

-- So I tried another solution of the Woocommerce documentation [`wc_update_product_stock()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_update_product_stock.html#16-54), that should return `@return bool | int | null`, but it returns the state of the product:

- Code - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZp9O.png
- Print - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKgWt.png

-- Place where I'm getting the product id:

- ID Place - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOvIN.png

-- And I have already manually changed the quantity and availability of inventory to check for changes and nothing happen!

If you need more information, know the cause of the problem and the possible solution, please, help me !!

*(English Skills W.I.P)*

Comment: The problem that it was a variation of product for this reason could not change as a single product. From this it was possible to make the change in the correct way